# Windows Identify Foundation: 2 tokens based on different certificates being recognised by R.Ps

Tags: .net, wif, asp.net-4.5

For technical reasons we have implemented two different STS websites in our application. These STS issue tokens which are based on different certificates.

We have a main application and a subset application and each are configured to use and trust one of these STS websites.

Both applications use the Claim Type Name to set the users name at login, and this is then surfaced in the relying party applications UI.

My problem is that if I login to one STS, everything is fine. When I login to the other application/STS, the name surfaced in the UI from the first login is replaced with that of the second login.

I can only assume that as the STS's are using completely different certificates to sign the tokens they will be ignored by the relying parties unless configured to trust within the web.config. This is how I have set it up.

From debugging, everything seems to work fine. The correct STS to used and the correct certificate is used when creating the Token.

I can see that the existing FedAuth cookie grows when I login to the second application so the claims for both sessions are being added to the same cookie.

I would appreciate if someone can offer some suggestions as to how to make the tokens issued by the STS completely independent of each other.

Thanks very much,
John

Comment: If you observe in debug that you do have both auth tokens in the session, what exactly your problem? not handling case where there is more than one tokens ?

Comment: Also what you refer to as subset application? is it subfolder in asp.net project?

Comment: The problem is that the Tokens are different and should essentially be treated as being completely independent. Changing the Claim type in one token should not affect the other, but this is what is happening. I would have thought that signing the tokens with different certificates would ensure that this is the case. The subset application is a separate application which is hosted in a different virtual directory to the main application. It offers a subset of the functionality available in the main application.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the correct behaviour, and both tokens are in fact different. If you hadn't add the 2nd  STS in the config, the authentications against that STS might succeed, but they will be rejected by WIF, because they would come from a "non-trusted" source (the undeclared STS).

If you add the 2nd STS as a "trusted issuer", the WIF (in your app) wil happily accept its tokens. The Claim Type "name" is simply what is mapped to `User.Name` property.

It'd probably help if you explained a little bit more what is it that you want to do. What shoudl happen in your app when someone logs in with the 2nd STS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The main application STS uses Forms authentication and asks for a username and password, then retrieves the roles from the DB and populates the Roles as Claims in the Token. The secondary application only uses Windows Authentication, and as such any user coming in through it should have restricted access. It is essentially a quick access lookup application. The problem I am trying to solve is that when the user logs into the main application, the roles are populated into the claim for the secondary application and the user can do far more than they should be able to

Comment: In response to your answer, the main application has a dedicated STS and only trusts tokens from there. The secondary application also has a dedicated STS and only trusts tokens from there. If both STS are based on different certificates, then how can this behaviour be correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is that neither Relying Party had a name set for the authentication cookie, so they both used "FedAuth". By explicitly giving them different names to use for the cookie in the cookieHandler, the problem was fixed.

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false" issuer="http://localhost:9006/App.AD_STS/" realm="http://localhost:6542/" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" path="/" name="AD_STS" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
```